# outline manager ,firewall rules are blocking incoming connections

Tags: vpn, outline

[{ OUTLINE VPN }](https://getoutline.org/en/home"download here")

> Server(**Linux **)

I had been configuring a server for outline Virtual private network:

1. I installed docker and enabled it.
2. Setup Firewall with a long list of rules allowing all the ports and IP's  ...

I also have an API key to the server.

However, the outline manager still informs me to open ports ranging `1024` to `65535`.

Is there any command for the server?

Comment: Perhaps posting the actual error, with the error code, might be useful! :)

Comment: fix the formatting issues and add more details.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. I tried to play with network settings in the VPS provider (Google cloud and Azure). I also tried ufw commands. However, there is a very simple solution to that, flush the rules and try again. You might need to reboot.

```
sudo iptables -F
```

Answer (score 0):

It depends on your Cloud provider.

On DigitalOcean, unless you set up Cloud Firewall, you can disable the firewall with

```
sudo ufw disable
```

Details at https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/ufw-essentials-common-firewall-rules-and-commands#disable-ufw

The automated server creation will take care of that for you on DigitalOcean and Google Cloud.

The Outline Manager provides instructions on how to set up the firewall on AWS.